# Validate files in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have validation:

```
if ($request->hasFile('otherFiles')) {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'otherFiles' => 'mimes:image/jpeg'
            ]);
        }
```

How can I add to this validation files type: DOC, DOCX, CSV, PDF, RTF, PNG, xlsx, XLS, TXT, BMP?

Comment: did you try by adding other mime type with `|` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'otherFiles.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'
```

for full mime type

```
'otherFiles.*' => 'mimetypes:image/jpeg,image/bmp,image/png'
```

[mime type validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-mimes)

for list of all mime types and their extensions
[mime types](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types)

Answer (score 2):

i have this code:

```
if ($request->hasfile('otherFiles')) {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'otherFiles' => 'required',
                'otherFiles.*' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,doc,docx,csv,rtf,xlsx,xls,txt,pdf'
            ]);
            foreach ($request->file('otherFiles') as $file) {
                $extension = strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension());
                $path = 'upload/other/';
                $uniqueName = md5($file . time());
                $file->move(public_path($path), $uniqueName . '.' . $extension);
            }
        }
```

and I have error: "otherFiles":["other files must  file type image/jpeg."

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" on the form in font-end

Comment: i have: <form {{ $novalidate  }} method="POST"
                                              action="{{ route('textPagesView', ['id' => $textPage->id ?? null]) }}"
                                              enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form form-horizontal form-bordered">

Comment: try remove jpeg